# Solve the following sequence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let a sequence be defined as $$a_n=\lim_ {x \to 0}{1-\cos (x)\cos(2x).....\cos (nx)\over x^2}$$
a)prove that the given sequence is monotonic and that it is not bounded above.
b)calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ({6a_n \over n^3})^{n^2 \over n+1}$$
NOTE:i am a high school student in the 12th grade

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? What is the context of the problem?

Comment: I would find  $a_n$ by using Maclaurin series. But that is my answer to nearly all these limit problems.

Comment: I am a high school student and i havent studied the maclaurin series. I have tried to calculate the sequence but failed..

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}1 - \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdot \dotsc\cdot \cos(nx)\cos((n+1)x) &= 1 - \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdot\dotsc\cdot \cos(nx)\\ &\quad + \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdot\dotsc\cdot \cos(nx)\bigl(1 - \cos((n+1)x)\bigr)\end{aligned}$$ If you know $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$, you can get $a_n$ via the recurrence above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it has yet to be posted, I thought it would be instructive to present the approach suggested by @DanielFischer.  We note that we can write

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac12(n+1)^2 \tag 1$$

Summing $(1)$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)&=a_{n}-a_1\\\\
a_n&=a_1+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1)^2\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\\\\
&=\frac{1}{12}n(n+1)(2n+1)
\end{align}$$

---

For the second part, we note that

$$\frac{6a_n}{n^3}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)$$

Therefore, the limit of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{6a_n}{n^3}\right)^{(n^2+1)/n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{6a_n}{n^3}\right)^{n\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how exactly did you obtain the first relation ? Shouldnt be there "="after $$a_n$$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And thank you for catching the typo.  I edited accordingly.  - Mark

Comment: Im glad to see such a nice person. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Using $\cos(x)=1-\frac12 x^2+O(x^4)$ we have

$$\frac{1-\prod_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)}{x^2}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2+O(x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital and the fact that
$$- \left(\prod \cos(kx)\right)' = 
\sum_{k=1}^n k\sin(kx)\prod_{j\not=k} \cos(jx).$$